# Send emails using Office365 integrated in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, office365

Just want to know if how can I use Office365 integrated in laravel on sending emails.

Thank you guys in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use below php code to send emails using Office365

```
<?php
require 'vendor/phpmailer/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.office365.com';
$mail->Port       = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Username = 'somebody@somewhere.com';
$mail->Password = 'YourPassword';
$mail->SetFrom('somebody@somewhere.com', 'FromEmail');
$mail->addAddress('recipient@domain.com', 'ToEmail');
//$mail->SMTPDebug  = 3;
//$mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {echo "debug level $level; message: $str";}; //$mail->Debugoutput = 'echo';
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Email could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Email has been sent.';
}
```

You can uncomment the commented code in case you receive any error.

You can also use Swift Mailer library in Laravel to send emails. The `.env` file should contain as default the following values:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=null
MAIL_HOST=null
MAIL_PORT=null
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

These are the default values, you need to replace it with your Office365 details like below :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.office365.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=Office365AccountEmail
MAIL_PASSWORD=Office365AccountPassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

For more details you can refer [this link](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/247/how-to-send-an-email-gmail-outlook-and-zoho-in-laravel)

Hope this will help you.

Comment: `MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tsl` there is a typo `tsl` should be`tls`

Comment: Hi Antonios, thank you for the correction. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use this Mail-Driver:
https://github.com/motze92/office365-mail

With SMTP and office365 we had many timeout problems and  temporarely errors. Sending mails over graph rest api works better.